# Reducing an array of values into object with their count using aggregation framework

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

We are using MongoDB to record statistics. The approach is to record each action for an object in its own document and later aggregate them on hourly basis and store them in different collection. Sample documents are below:

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e05de1e86029610dc2c6f9c"),
    "object_type" : 1,
    "object_id" : 1003,
    "browser" : "chrome",
    "os" : "osx",
    "device" : "android",
    "category" : 3,
    "country" : "gb",
    "action" : "impression",
    "date_added" : ISODate("2019-12-26T19:00:00.000Z")
},{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e06226586029610db417b7a"),
    "object_type" : 1,
    "object_id" : 1003,
    "browser" : "firefox",
    "os" : "osx",
    "device" : "lg_tv",
    "category" : 1,
    "country" : "pe",
    "action" : "impression",
    "date_added" : ISODate("2019-12-25T19:00:00.000Z")
},{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e06226586029610db417b7b"),
    "object_type" : 1,
    "object_id" : 1009,
    "browser" : "uc_browser",
    "os" : "osx",
    "device" : "android",
    "category" : 4,
    "country" : "ru",
    "action" : "view",
    "date_added" : ISODate("2019-12-25T19:00:00.000Z")
}]
```

Output should be:

```
[{
    "object_id": 1003,
    "object_type": 1,
    "action": "impression",
    "total": 2,
    "date": "2019-12-26 19:00:00",
    "browsers": { "firefox": 1, "chrome": 1 },
    "systems": { "osx": 2 },
    "countries": { "gb": 1, "pe": 1 },
    "devices": { "android": 1, "lg_tv": 1 },
    "categories": { "3": 1, "1": 1 }
},
{
    "object_id": 1009,
    "object_type": 1,
    "action": "view",
    "total": 1,
    "date": "2019-12-26 19:00:00",
    "browsers": { "uc_browser": 1 },
    "systems": { "osx": 1 },
    "countries": { "ru": 1 },
    "devices": { "android": 1 },
    "categories": { "4": 1 }
}]
```

Aggregation pipeline:

```
[
  {
    "$match": {
      "date_added": {
        "$gte": {
          "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1576820825000"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "object_id": "$object_id",
        "object_type": "$object_type",
        "action": "$action",
        "date": {
          "$dateToString": {
            "format": "%Y-%m-%d %H-00-00",
            "date": "$date_added"
          }
        }
      },
      "total": {
        "$sum": 1
      },
      "countries": {
        "$push": "$country"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "action": "$_id.action",
      "object_id": "$_id.object_id",
      "object_type": "$_id.object_type",
      "date": "$_id.date",
      "total": 1,
      "countries": 1,
      "systems": 1,
      "devices": 1,
      "categories": 1,
      "_id": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "total": -1
    }
  }
]
```

This pipeline provides total of an object for a certain action on given hour and push each country into `countries` array - for readability removed other indexes from `$group`.

I’m stuck at transforming `countries` array into desired object. Two question popped in my mind.

1. Is it possible with single aggregation pipeline?
2. Should I just return documents using above pipeline and process rest of the indexes with scripting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It's possible, but a bit *tedious*...**

You need to `$group` each new field in the next stage and acumulate previous fields.

**ASSUMPTION**

Your expected result for `"object_id": 1003` with `total:2`, but `date_added` is 2019-12-2**6** and 2019-12-2**5**. So, I've changed to 2019-12-2**6** both documents.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "date_added": {
        "$gte": {
          "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1576820825000"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "object_id": "$object_id",
        "object_type": "$object_type",
        "action": "$action",
        "date": {
          "$dateToString": {
            "format": "%Y-%m-%d %H-00-00",
            "date": "$date_added",
            timezone: "GMT"
          }
        }
      },
      data: {
        "$push": "$$ROOT"
      },
      total: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: "$_id",
        "tmp": "$data.category"
      },
      data: {
        $push: "$data"
      },
      total: {
        $first: "$total"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id._id",
      data: {
        $push: "$data"
      },
      total: {
        $first: "$total"
      },
      categories: {
        $push: {
          k: {
            $toString: "$_id.tmp"
          },
          v: "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: "$_id",
        "tmp": "$data.device"
      },
      categories: {
        $first: "$categories"
      },
      data: {
        $push: "$data"
      },
      total: {
        $first: "$total"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id._id",
      data: {
        $push: "$data"
      },
      total: {
        $first: "$total"
      },
      categories: {
        $first: "$categories"
      },
      devices: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id.tmp",
          v: "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: "$_id",
        "tmp": "$data.country"
      },
      devices: {
        $first: "$devices"
      },
      categories: {
        $first: "$categories"
      },
      data: {
        $push: "$data"
      },
      total: {
        $first: "$total"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id._id",
      data: {
        $push: "$data"
      },
      total: {
        $first: "$total"
      },
      devices: {
        $first: "$devices"
      },
      categories: {
        $first: "$categories"
      },
      countries: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id.tmp",
          v: "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: "$_id",
        "tmp": "$data.os"
      },
      countries: {
        $first: "$countries"
      },
      devices: {
        $first: "$devices"
      },
      categories: {
        $first: "$categories"
      },
      data: {
        $push: "$data"
      },
      total: {
        $first: "$total"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id._id",
      data: {
        $push: "$data"
      },
      total: {
        $first: "$total"
      },
      countries: {
        $first: "$countries"
      },
      devices: {
        $first: "$devices"
      },
      categories: {
        $first: "$categories"
      },
      systems: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id.tmp",
          v: "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: "$_id",
        "tmp": "$data.browser"
      },
      systems: {
        $first: "$systems"
      },
      countries: {
        $first: "$countries"
      },
      devices: {
        $first: "$devices"
      },
      categories: {
        $first: "$categories"
      },
      data: {
        $push: "$data"
      },
      total: {
        $first: "$total"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id._id",
      data: {
        $push: "$data"
      },
      total: {
        $first: "$total"
      },
      systems: {
        $first: "$systems"
      },
      countries: {
        $first: "$countries"
      },
      devices: {
        $first: "$devices"
      },
      categories: {
        $first: "$categories"
      },
      browsers: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id.tmp",
          v: "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      action: "$_id.action",
      date: "$_id.date",
      object_id: "$_id.object_id",
      object_type: "$_id.object_type",
      total: 1,
      categories: {
        $arrayToObject: "$categories"
      },
      countries: {
        $arrayToObject: "$countries"
      },
      devices: {
        $arrayToObject: "$devices"
      },
      systems: {
        $arrayToObject: "$systems"
      },
      browsers: {
        $arrayToObject: "$browsers"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      object_id: 1,
      date: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dKOQDDEG0_F)

**Note:** Other approach was to use `$facet` and create fields separately and then merge them into final object, but [MongoPlayground sometimes worked buggy](https://mongoplayground.net/p/s-0RxIJHPbr) (click Run button several times and you get different result)

Comment: Thanks. Playground is showing the excepted output. I'll try both of these pipelines on larger dataset. In term of performance which one is better `$facet` or multiple `$group`? `$facet` looks more elegant.

Comment: It has the same performance. `$facet` is designed to do combine different aggregation in 1 step. And if you change expected result, it's more easier to change `$facet` than `$group`. **Note:** Each pipeline output document cannot exceed 16Mb and use the `allowDiskUse` option to enable aggregation pipeline stages to write data to temporary files.